# Django users can't login after I create an account but admin can

Tags: django

I register a user succesfully. But then when I try to login it says username or password is wrong. This only happens for normal users. Superadmin can login without any problem.

login view

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Logged in succesfully')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username or password is wrong')
            return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

register view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = Account.objects.create_user(
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password
            )
            user.phone = phone
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Created an account succesfully!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

If you want me to send any other code please specify so I edit the question

Comment: What is the value of `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? does it specify your `Account` model correctly? What does `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()` return?

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account' I specified it like that. I couldn't understand the second one

Comment: Because in `auth.authenticate` you missing parameter `request`. It's always return None. Try fix like this: `user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`.

Comment: It still gives an error as wrong username or password

Comment: Did you try restart server after you change a code?

Comment: Yes I even cleared the cache

Comment: OMG when create user, that's not hash password. Your password when you save is a plain text. Please use `make_password()` to hash it.

Comment: I am sorry I am still learning django. Will this solve my problem? I just want to fix this

Comment: Yes that's will solve your problem. That's why your admin account can login.

Comment: Another approach to better utilize django features would be to use the built it system for user authentication in django, it will handle all this hassle for you and i really suggest reading the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) or for a more beginner friendly tutorial try [this one](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial), let it fetch and create the user for you and write even less code with the specific views designed for said purpose